# Github issue. fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github, push

I faced this issue too many times, it occurs while **pushing commits to Github**. As I searched for, it looks to be caused by **slow internet connection**, is it true? can I push it without having fast uplink connection?

There is some logs that I collected from.

brief error log:

> error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
> send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
> Everything up-to-date

**Full error log keypoint:**

> **Info: TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):**

Full error log is [**HERE**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FfKwCFmaVLvdxMq-1aQAJlCWiW2Y8uRe/view?usp=sharing)

Here is a list of what I do to solve this issue without changing anything

- `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`
- `git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0`
- `git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 999999`
- `set GIT_HTTP_MAX_REQUEST_BUFFER=100M`

Screenshot:
[image]

---

**Thank a lots**

Comment: *As I searched for, it looks to be caused by slow internet connection, is it true?* It *can* be. It can be caused by other problems as well. You'll need to diagnose the network problems before you can be certain of any particular fix, since this sort of problem tends to be intermittent. You might change something and try again and have it work, not because of what you changed, but rather just because of luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, diagnosing network problems is very tricky, as there can be so many different ones. You are using https: do you have a proxy? Do you have a security appliance? Are you running some fancy anti-virus software? All of these can introduce errors.

Comment: Thanks @torek, I tried several times in several days, but nothing else happened, It goes out of luck , I faced same issue a month ago, after a day without changing anything I tried to push, it works and this thing didn't happen.
And about the second staff, I don't have any proxy and anti-virus, just have a VPN from my browser not the PC.

**Note: My Downlink speed is 10Mbps and Uplink is 0.35Mbps**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is the answer

Here we go, I got my answer after trying too many ways in three days, for whoever will face this issue, do this stuff (read all below before starting):

- At first, Open **Git Bash**
- then, follow this [instructions](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/server/ssh/how-to-add-ssh-keys-to-your-github-account/) to generate SSH code and attach it to Github account.
- Go to Github repository page
- Click on *Code* button
- Change it to *SSH*
- Copy **SSH CODE** and use below, *I determine your SSH code is **git@github.com:user/user-repo.git***
- In your terminal write `git remote add origin-ssh git@github.com:user/user-repo.git`, **SSH CODE** is which you copied one step before
- And finally push by `git push -u origin-ssh`
- Congrats

---

Notes:

- Don't add **passphrase** while generating SSH code if you are new to SSH, just trigger Enter button.
- Remember, *git@github.com:user/user-repo.git* is not your real SSH code, I use it as an example, use which Github gives you, it's an unique code.

Answer (score 0):

with the above answer while copying ssh, make sure you copy public key like this -

```
$cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```