# Github Error: fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, repository, push

Good afternoon,

I am trying to push all my code on to Github using these following commands:

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/ZpoDavay/zpo.git
git push -u origin main
```

However it is **returning this error**:

```
(56/fatal: unable to read 178348487399937489f488493d
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ZpoDavay/zpo.git'
```

### *Note:*

It is important to add that I cloned another user's repository, but set the URL origin to my own repository by doing the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin
```

I would assume that this issue stems from me not having proper access and permission to push the code, due to it originally being a cloned repository. But I'am not completely sure, since I am new to Github.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github issue. fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276233/github-issue-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Comment: There's something particularly odd here: `178348487399937489f488493d` looks like a Git hash ID, but it's *too short*, it's only 26 characters long and it should be 40. Other than that, the symptoms you're seeing would result from a damaged repository. Standard Git commands can't damage the repository (unless Git has a bug) but storing a repository in a Dropbox or other cloud-synced folder would do it.

Comment: To check for repository damage, run `git fsck`. Note that many of the messages that `git fsck` can print are normal and don't indicate any actual error: it takes careful reading to pick out the errors, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was facing the same issue while pushing some files ***(.cpp & .exe).***
I've tried so many fixes around here and still getting the same error.
After experimenting with different types of files, I've found that if I don't push the ***.exe*** files, everything is doing just fine.
So, I had to create a ***.gitignore*** file and ignored the files with ***.exe*** extension.
By doing this way, the error is gone. I hope this will be helpful in some cases.